# How to enable Neo4J similarity algorithms

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Neo4j 3.5.9 from a Docker image, and I'm trying to use the [Jaccard Similarity algorithm](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/experimental-algorithms/jaccard/). However, when I run a query like this:

```
RETURN algo.similarity.jaccard([1,2,3], [1,2,4,5]) AS similarity
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Unknown function 'algo.similarity.jaccard' (line 1, column 8 (offset: 7))
```

"RETURN algo.similarity.jaccard([1,2,3], [1,2,4,5]) AS similarity"

Do I need to enable this (experimental) algorithm somehow in the docker container? Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Similarity algorithms are part of the neo4j graph algorithm library. Have you tried following the installation instructions here: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/introduction/#_installation ?

Comment: @stellasia thanks for that, I didn't know I had to install them manually. I'll look into this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep using docker you can install the graph algorithms library in the following way:

1. [Download the library](https://neo4j.com/download-center/) and unpack it somewhere (`$HOME/servers/neo4j/plugins` in the example
2. Run docker image with additional parameters:

   ```
   docker run -p7687:7687 -p7474:7474 \
       -v $HOME/servers/neo4j/plugins:/plugins \ 
       --env NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=algo\.\* \ 
       neo4j:3.5.8
   ```

`-v $HOME/servers/neo4j/plugins:/plugins` - mounts the folder on left side as `plugins` directory, change accordingly

`--env NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=algo\.\*` - sets the configuration option, described here https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/introduction/#_neo4j_server, the syntax with NEO4J prefix and underscores is a convention for the [Neo4j docker image](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.5/docker/configuration/#docker-environment-variables).